# Why do Firefox and Chrome just decide not to render a chunk of my page?

Tags: html, css, debugging, browser

http://jsfiddle.net/8GaB9/

The entire "vehicles" section is just gone in Firefox 3.6.13 and Chrome 10. Works fine in IE.

If I add some text right before the `<div class="row">` that contains the vehicles, *then* the whole section appears.

Why's that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either add display:inline-block; to your row class in your CSS (like Sotiris suggests as well) or close your parent row div that contains Pickup, Drop-off, and Vehicles and have Vehicles on the outside.  Either way fixes the display issues inside of Chrome and FF.

Comment: Ohhhh.... I didn't close the row? I meant to! Got too long... couldn't match up the divs :p Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

try to add `display: inline-block;` for the `.row`

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/8GaB9/2/

Comment: Nice! Not sure why that fixes it... but I'll take it.

Comment: +1 due to the solution working and referenced your solution as well.